Clear value of AwesomeNotifications().getInitialNotificationAction() in awesome notification after opening it for first time from the background
I am using awesome notification for a foreground service and on notification click I want to open a specific location even if the app is closed. I implemented it perfectly by using AwesomeNotifications().getInitialNotificationAction() which checks if the app is opened using a notification action or not, but the problem is it retains the action button as long as the the service is ongoing and the notification is present in the application.
My main app
Future<void> main() async {
  ...;
  await Future.wait([
    NotificationService.initializeNotification()
  ]);
  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

The notification service controller
class NotificationService {
  static ReceivedAction? initialAction;
  static Future<void> initializeNotification() async {
    await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
      null,
      [
        NotificationChannel(
          channelGroupKey: NotificationConstants.timerChannelGroup,
          channelKey: NotificationConstants.timerChannel,
          channelName: NotificationConstants.timerChannel,
          channelDescription: NotificationConstants.timerChannelDescription,
          importance: NotificationImportance.High,
          channelShowBadge: true,
          onlyAlertOnce: true,
          playSound: true,
        )
      ],
      channelGroups: [
        NotificationChannelGroup(
          channelGroupKey: NotificationConstants.timerChannelGroup,
          channelGroupName: 'Group 1',
        )
      ],
    );

    // await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed().then(
    //   (isAllowed) async {
    //     if (!isAllowed) {
    //       await AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
    //     }
    //   },
    // );

    await AwesomeNotifications().setListeners(
      onActionReceivedMethod: onActionReceivedMethod,
      onNotificationCreatedMethod: onNotificationCreatedMethod,
      onNotificationDisplayedMethod: onNotificationDisplayedMethod,
      onDismissActionReceivedMethod: onDismissActionReceivedMethod,
    );

    initialAction = await AwesomeNotifications().getInitialNotificationAction();
    safePrint("Initial Action ${initialAction?.payload}");
  }

  /// Use this method to detect when a new notification or a schedule is created
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onNotificationCreatedMethod(ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
    safePrint('onNotificationCreatedMethod');
  }

  /// Use this method to detect every time that a new notification is displayed
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onNotificationDisplayedMethod(ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
    safePrint('onNotificationDisplayedMethod');
  }

  /// Use this method to detect if the user dismissed a notification
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onDismissActionReceivedMethod(ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    safePrint('onDismissActionReceivedMethod');
  }

  /// Use this method to detect when the user taps on a notification or action button
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onActionReceivedMethod(ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    safePrint('onActionReceivedMethod');
    safePrint("payload ${receivedAction.payload}, button key ${receivedAction.buttonKeyPressed.length}");
    if (receivedAction.buttonKeyPressed.trim().isEmpty) {
      context.go(Routes.someDestination, extra: {
          'someArgument': ''some value
      });
    }
  }

  static Future<void> showNotification({
    required final String title,
    required final String body,
    final Map<String, String>? payload,
    final List<NotificationActionButton>? actionButtons
  }) async {

    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
        id: NotificationConstants.timerChannelNotificationId,
        channelKey: NotificationConstants.timerChannel,
        title: title,
        body: body,
        payload: payload,
      ),
      actionButtons: actionButtons,
    );
  }
}

And in the SplashScreen page I have used the receivedAction like this
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  late ReceivedAction? receivedAction;
  late final SplashCubit _splashCubit;
  late final GoRouter _router;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _router = GoRouter.of(context);
    _splashCubit = context.read();
    _splashCubit.changeOpacity();
    receivedAction = NotificationService.initialAction;
    safePrint("Initial Action ${receivedAction?.payload}");
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      if (receivedAction != null && receivedAction?.payload != null) {
        context.go(Routes.someDestination, extra: {
          'someArgument': ''some value
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SomeWidget();
    );
  }
}


can you share a screenshot, so that we can understand what action btn you are talking about. And please give a better explanation. I really did not understood your prblm.
